# multiple processes named 'systemd' running simultaneously (w/ one pid 1)

Tags: linux, arch-linux, systemd

I have multiple processes named systemd running simultaneously on my Arch Linux machine. At least one of them is PID 1.

Is this normal?

Answer (score 3):

It has been normal for Arch Linux since October 2012, yes.

`systemd` is now your system manager and service manager.  It runs as process #1.

The other processes could be per-user instances of `systemd`, instances of `systemd` in a "container" (if you have containers), ephemeral services that `systemd` is right in the middle of spawning, or simply programs such as `systemd-journald` where you haven't spotted the double-barrelled nature of the program name.  ☺  The world cannot tell you more with what little information you've provided.

### Further reading

- Pierre Schmitz (2012-10-07). [*Install medium 2012.10.06 introduces systemd*](https://archlinux.org/news/install-medium-20121006-introduces-systemd/).  Arch Linux News.
- [*`systemd`*](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd).  ArchWiki.
- [*Arch `systemd` container*](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_systemd_container).  ArchWiki.

Comment: I clarified my situation in an edit. Upon changing my login shell from `zsh` (which hung on start and thus eliminated my access to TTY and GUI terminals) back to `bash` `systemd` no longer spawned multiple persistent (I assume hanging) processes. Weird stuff.